# do-release-upgrade cannot authenticate

Tags: upgrade, gnupg, do-release-upgrade

How do I fix this error?

```
st@ThinkPad-T450s:~/Downloads$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [836 B]                                                     
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1.264 kB]                                                            
Fetched 1.264 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                           
authenticate 'zesty.tar.gz' against 'zesty.tar.gz.gpg' 
Authentication failed
Authenticating the upgrade failed. There may be a problem with the network or with the server.
```

I get the same error with `update-manager -d`.

I know I can turn off gpg authentication in apt-get but not in do-release-upgrade or update-manager

Comment: What is your current Ubuntu version?

Comment: My currect Ubuntu version is: `Release:        16.10, Codename:       yakkety`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You have the latest version. Why are you trying to upgrade it?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to delete trusted keys from /etc/apt dir.

```
rm -rf /etc/apt/trusted*
```

After this, you must to update your packages list:

```
apt-get update
```

You will see some error with missing keys.
Now, you can re-import keys:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys KEY_ID
```

After this, `do-release-upgrade` will work correct.

Comment: Didn't help, still can't upgrade to focal.

Comment: Didn't help but this did: https://askubuntu.com/a/1288298/566486