# unable to upgrade to xubuntu 20.04 from 18.04 as Repositories Not Found

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, xubuntu

Have xUbuntu 18.04 (LTS) installed in a duel boot configuration.  Tried to upgrade to xUbuntu 20.04 but upgrades always fail as it tells me "No internet connection".  The error seems related to the Chrome web-browser Repositories. I'd prefer not to uninstall Chrome at this point as that's how I browse the web and post to SE.

The release notes for 20.04 don't list the problem "No Internet Connection" and discuss nothing about Repositories.

I've been working on this problem literally for 2 months. It appears that a lot of people have difficulty upgrading to 20.04.  I started with 16.04, upgraded to 18.04 but never had problems like I do with 20.04 before!!!  Also a lot of the Repository management info is 5+ years old and uses noncurrent commands.

===========================================================================
Update -- this is the error I'm getting

> sudo apt upgrade
> {presumabley this upgrades the repository list?}

```
.....
Get:39 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse i386 Packages [10.6 kB]
Get:40 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse Translation-en [5,452 B]
Get:41 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]
Reading package lists... Done                                      
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 78BD65473CB3BD13
E: The repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

===========================================================================
"do-release-upgrade"
this also fails: see below  I prefer to fix repositories as at least I get some useable error messages.

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1,554 B]                                                                          
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,341 kB]                                                                                   
Fetched 1,343 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                  
authenticate 'focal.tar.gz' against 'focal.tar.gz.g
Authentication failed
Authenticating the upgrade failed. There may be a problem with the network or with the server.
```

===========================================================================

Comment: How are you trying to do the upgrade ? What exact steps.

Comment: you don't have to do anything with repositories. `do-release-upgrade` will handle it for you.

Comment: You shouldn’t need to do this manually. It’s literally [a couple of mouse clicks](https://docs.xubuntu.org/latest/user/C/migrating-upgrading.html) or a couple of commands in a terminal … 

Comment: ""No internet connection". Let's check. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `ip addr show` If you have no internet connection then you will not be able to reach any repositories.

Comment: Added new info to the orig post.   Apparently there is a problem with the Repositories for the Chrome browser which I'm using.     do-release-upgrade
also fails  As mentioned I've been working on the upgrade a long time.  It's very difficult to go from 18.04 to 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer on another thread relating to Ubuntu upgrade to 20.04
[Upgrade to 20.04, authentication failed.  answer by Anuga](https://askubuntu.com/a/1311079/796532)

Comment: to continue, I was thus able to upgrade to xubuntu 20.04.  It also purged a lot of old packages that were not being used.